# Dynamically use Datasource based on groupid Liferay 6.0

Tags: java, model-view-controller, tomcat, liferay, portlet

how to dynamically used different database based on groupid from logging user? For example is the group name XL I want to use database XLPortlet ,and if user iwth groupname Carto using Database CartoPortlet,how to achieve this in liferay??can we use service builder to achieve this?I've try using ext-spring to connect other database than lportal,but It doesnt dynamic any idea how to achieve this? Thank's

Regards

Danial

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question correctly but service builder can create tables and portlets that are group and portal instance aware.

Just make sure to have the following in your service.xml

```
<!-- Audit fields -->
<column name="companyId" type="long" />
<column name="groupId" type="long" />
<column name="userId" type="long" />
<column name="userName" type="String" />
<column name="createDate" type="Date" />
<column name="modifiedDate" type="Date" />
```

Then you would not have to have separate databases for each community the data would be community aware in one database.

Comment: well I want to connect to other database based on logging user....if the user is member of group dataB then it switch to database dataB,,,if user is member of group dataA then it siwtch to database dataA.... IF i'm using service builder,, it's only can use one database,,i've tried to use ext-spring..still no luck